# Can't load phpBB installed in a subfolder inside wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, phpbb3

I have a wordpress installed in a domain and phpBB inside a folder in that domain. The problem is I can access the folder, as Wordpress is not redirecting to it.

What can I make?

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem, and with much trial and error:

I figured out that in order to complete the installation, I need to visit the domain.com/forumfolder/phpBB3

NOT with a lowercase phpbb3 but as it is on the file with upper case BB: "domain.com/forumfolder/phpBB3".

Hope this helps!